# save JObject as Base64 Encoded file

Tags: c#, json, json.net, bson

I'm reading a Json file into a JObject `myParams` with this code. This works well

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("config.json"))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
{
    JObject myParams = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
}
```

What I want is then to encode the information and save it back into another file.
This code reads a file, encodes it and directly saves it. It works

```
using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("filenameEncoded.bson", true))
    ​w.Write(Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes("filename.json")));
```

However I don't want to read a file and immediately encode it.

Instead I want to import myParams with the first piece of code, do some modifications to the JObject and then encode it and save it encoded in a file.

The problem is that then I cannot use `Convert.ToBase64String` on `myParams` since it expect bytes instead of a JObject.

How can I encode and save my JObject myParams into an encoded file?

Comment: Have you tried to pass this `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myParams.ToString(Formatting.None))` to the `Convert.ToBase64String`? (Obviously `UTF8` should be replaced if the source file was in ASCII for example)

Comment: Just tried, (you mean UTF8 instead of UT8?). It generated an encoded file. Will try to decode it and see if it matches the original one.

Comment: Yes I've meant UT8, sorry for the typo

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks

Comment: What is the actual goal? Base64-encoding is a way to store binary data as text. Json is already text, so you will not gain anything. If you want to store Bson data you should probably use [BsonWriter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm)

Comment: I want to obfuscate the json. so parameters are not trivial to change. Bson will also be an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the following parameter to your `Convert.ToBase64String` method call:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myParams.ToString(Formatting.None))
```

- the `ToString` call on the `JObject` is [overwritten to emit Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/tostring.htm)
- the `Formatting.None` parameter will omit indentation
- the `Encoding.XYZ.GetGetBytes` converts a string into a `byte[]`